# I'm trying to add an URL image to my javafx application

Tags: java, user-interface, url, javafx, combobox

I've read a XML including data from different weatherstation (WeerStation) including a URL. Now when you choose a weatherstation from the combobox I want to show that URL in my application like a little weather app but I can't get it done...

```
public class WeatherGUI extends Application {
ComboBox combo;
ArrayList<WeerStation> list = new ArrayList();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

    BuienRadarController controller = new BuienRadarController(this);
    list = controller.getStations();
    combo = new ComboBox();
    combo.getItems().addAll(list);
    combo.setPromptText("Het weer in");

    VBox vbox = new VBox(8);
    vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Label label1 = new Label();
    Label label2 = new Label();
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label1,label2);

    Button button = new Button("Kies");
    button.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        WeerStation station = (WeerStation) combo.getValue();
        label1.setText("Het weer in " + station.toString() + ":");
        label2.setText(station.getBeschrijving());
        // ADD url to vbox
    });

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(6));
    layout.getChildren().addAll(combo,button,vbox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("BuienRadar");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to show that URL in my application"? Interpreted literally, that would mean you just do `someLabel.setText(station.getURL().toString());` (or similar). But perhaps you mean you want to show the actual HTML you get from that URL? In that case you could use a [`WebView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html).

Comment: Or if it's a URL just for an image, you can just pass it directly to an [`ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#ImageView-java.lang.String-)...

Comment: Okay thanks but how do i transform an URL to an image?

Comment: Never mind i got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the URL is a URL whose content is an image in a standard format (e.g. png), you can declare an `ImageView` and set the image to an `Image` created from the URL:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

    BuienRadarController controller = new BuienRadarController(this);
    list = controller.getStations();
    combo = new ComboBox();
    combo.getItems().addAll(list);
    combo.setPromptText("Het weer in");

    VBox vbox = new VBox(8);
    vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Label label1 = new Label();
    Label label2 = new Label();
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label1,label2,imageView);

    Button button = new Button("Kies");
    button.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        WeerStation station = (WeerStation) combo.getValue();
        label1.setText("Het weer in " + station.toString() + ":");
        label2.setText(station.getBeschrijving());
        // ADD url to vbox
        imageView.setImage(new Image(station.getURL().toExternalForm()));
    });

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(6));
    layout.getChildren().addAll(combo,button,vbox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("BuienRadar");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```